# Call a web service from a Broadcast Receiver in Android

Tags: android, web-services, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentservice

I'm developing an Android application in which user can fill different textboxes in a specific template.
The layout has a "SEND" button that when clicked, sends data to a web service (REST).
However if the connection is not avaible, data has to be stored in a local database. When connection is available again, data stored in the local db has to be sent online and the db must be empty.

My idea is to use an Intent Service with a Result Receiver to call the WS.
To manage the connectivity, I want to use a broadcast receiver that, when connectivity turn on, calls the intent service.

Could it be a fine solution?

My doubts are:

1. Which is the best way to get data from my db in the intent service?
2. How can I manage the offline call? I want that when the app is on background, if connectivity turns on, web service is called and I want to receive the response from it to decide if I can delete data from db (because it is been sent) or not.
3. When I call WS using button, I can receive the response directly in the activity, but when the call is done in background how can I manage my response?

Thanks